# Adding 2 dictionary entries from one string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have the following code:

```
new_dict = {}
text = "Yes: No Maybe: So"
```

I want to split the string up into 2 dictionary elements like so:

```
new_dict = {'Yes':'No', 'Maybe':'So'}
```

I tried to split the string up into a list in the same fashion to get a brief idea on how to do it, but I haven't had much success.

Comment: If you have access what `text` should be, you'd better add some kind of delimiter like `;`. By the way, dirty and fast solution is to explode string on space, then take pairs from array (remove `:` from the first one and add it to dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
text = "Yes: No Maybe: So"
words = [w.rstrip(':') for w in text.split()]
new_dict = dict(zip(words[::2], words[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

If each colon is followed by a space, `str.split()` will work fine for you:

```
tokens = (s.rstrip(":") for s in text.split())
new_dict = dict(zip(tokens, tokens))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "Yes: No Maybe: So"
>>> dict(re.findall(r'(\w+): (\w+)', text))
{'Maybe': 'So', 'Yes': 'No'}
```

or the more efficient:

```
>>> dict(m.groups() for m in re.finditer(r'(\w+): (\w+)', text))
{'Maybe': 'So', 'Yes': 'No'}
```